# More scaling control in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, svg

I recently asked a question about scaling an SVG / Raphael JS layout to fit an entire screen using percentages and transformations. What I didn't fully realize, is that SVG (or, at least, Raphael) scales from the center, which is no good. This makes it look a little odd when trying to align various elements.

My design goal is to create a base layout at 1280 x 720 and have it automatically detect the screen resolution to fit the height and keep its aspect ratio. The important content fits right in the middle, and two panels can slide in or out if the width is too small, or whatever (need to work on that later).

The solution I was thinking about (which I haven't really tested), was to pretty much ignore element.transform(), and create a custom scaling function. Each element would, somewhere, require an additional attribute where it is to be scaled to (for example, bottom-right corner, top, etc). And, the, the element would just be redrawn with the new dimensions. An element that has its 'anchor' set to top, would shift one pixel to the top and left, and expand one pixel to the right at a time. Or, something like that. As for text, I was just thinking about using percentages for the font size.

So, my question before I start tinkering, is- are there any SVG-based javascript libraries out there they have this functionality built in already? I was looking at Snap, svg.js and D3 (which I did not understand at all), but I couldn't find anything related. Or, are there some things I am missing with Raphael?

Or, maybe I am thinking about this too much and going about it wrong?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `viewbox()` method: http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#geometry/viewbox

Comment: Yeah! I forgot how I found it, but it worked perfectly and then I kinda forgot about this question >.> But, thanks :)